# Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so'

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, upgrade

I got issue with many commands. For example : I write **`php -v`** command and it gives error like this see below :

```
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache.so' (tried: ext/opcache.so (ext/opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/opcache.so.so (ext/opcache.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: ext/curl (ext/curl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/curl.so (ext/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: ext/intl (ext/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/intl.so (ext/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap' (tried: ext/imap (ext/imap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/imap.so (ext/imap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: ext/mbstring (ext/mbstring: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/mbstring.so (ext/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: ext/mysqli (ext/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/mysqli.so (ext/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'soap' (tried: ext/soap (ext/soap: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/soap.so (ext/soap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: ext/xsl (ext/xsl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xsl.so (ext/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo.so' (tried: ext/pdo.so (ext/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/pdo.so.so (ext/pdo.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xml.so' (tried: ext/xml.so (ext/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xml.so.so (ext/xml.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bcmath.so' (tried: ext/bcmath.so (ext/bcmath.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/bcmath.so.so (ext/bcmath.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'calendar.so' (tried: ext/calendar.so (ext/calendar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/calendar.so.so (ext/calendar.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ctype.so' (tried: ext/ctype.so (ext/ctype.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/ctype.so.so (ext/ctype.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl.so' (tried: ext/curl.so (ext/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/curl.so.so (ext/curl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dom.so' (tried: ext/dom.so (ext/dom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/dom.so.so (ext/dom.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif.so' (tried: ext/exif.so (ext/exif.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/exif.so.so (ext/exif.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo.so' (tried: ext/fileinfo.so (ext/fileinfo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/fileinfo.so.so (ext/fileinfo.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ftp.so' (tried: ext/ftp.so (ext/ftp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/ftp.so.so (ext/ftp.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext.so' (tried: ext/gettext.so (ext/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/gettext.so.so (ext/gettext.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'iconv.so' (tried: ext/iconv.so (ext/iconv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/iconv.so.so (ext/iconv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: ext/imagick.so (ext/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/imagick.so.so (ext/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'json.so' (tried: ext/json.so (ext/json.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/json.so.so (ext/json.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: ext/mbstring.so (ext/mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/mbstring.so.so (ext/mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'phar.so' (tried: ext/phar.so (ext/phar.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/phar.so.so (ext/phar.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'posix.so' (tried: ext/posix.so (ext/posix.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/posix.so.so (ext/posix.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'readline.so' (tried: ext/readline.so (ext/readline.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/readline.so.so (ext/readline.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'shmop.so' (tried: ext/shmop.so (ext/shmop.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/shmop.so.so (ext/shmop.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'simplexml.so' (tried: ext/simplexml.so (ext/simplexml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/simplexml.so.so (ext/simplexml.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sockets.so' (tried: ext/sockets.so (ext/sockets.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/sockets.so.so (ext/sockets.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvmsg.so' (tried: ext/sysvmsg.so (ext/sysvmsg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/sysvmsg.so.so (ext/sysvmsg.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvsem.so' (tried: ext/sysvsem.so (ext/sysvsem.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/sysvsem.so.so (ext/sysvsem.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sysvshm.so' (tried: ext/sysvshm.so (ext/sysvshm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/sysvshm.so.so (ext/sysvshm.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'tokenizer.so' (tried: ext/tokenizer.so (ext/tokenizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/tokenizer.so.so (ext/tokenizer.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'wddx.so' (tried: ext/wddx.so (ext/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/wddx.so.so (ext/wddx.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlreader.so' (tried: ext/xmlreader.so (ext/xmlreader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xmlreader.so.so (ext/xmlreader.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xmlwriter.so' (tried: ext/xmlwriter.so (ext/xmlwriter.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xmlwriter.so.so (ext/xmlwriter.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl.so' (tried: ext/xsl.so (ext/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ext/xsl.so.so (ext/xsl.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.23-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct  8 2019 05:31:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

I have tried followings but it is not working:-

```
sed "s/^zend_extension=.*opcache.so/zend_extension=$(find $(pwd) -name opcache.so | sed 's/\//\\\//g')/g" bin/php7.2/bin/php.ini | tee bin/php7.2/bin/php.ini
```

I am using **linuxmint OS**.

help should be appreciated

Comment: Did you not try to mix releases? Try to check if all rest of required libraries for php extension you have installed on your system (with `ldd` command).

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: What means "lts" - what is this? I'm writing about `ldd` ;)

Comment: I copy paste this. "ldd --help"

Comment: `ldd /path/to/the/php/extension/lib/file.so` and paste the result

Comment: ldd: /path/to/the/php/extension/lib/file.so: No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100008/discussion-between-chirag-p-and-mariaczi).